# ScrollView in Custom Cell on TableView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have custom cell on my table view which I've created with nib file. I have there 2 horizontal `scrollViews`. Target platform is iOS 7.

On Cell `XIB` file I've created "constrants" for every `tableView` (because I'm using `autolayout`).

On my Custom cell implementation file I have such code:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{

   self.SwitchPageSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, 240);
   self.SwitchPageSV.scrollEnabled = YES;
   self.SwitchPageSV.delegate = self;

   self.ButtonsSV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 40);
   self.SwitchPageSV.scrollEnabled = YES;

}
```

And it is working like a charm. But when I go from this table view to other View Controller and go back, scroll view does not work anymore. I have to scroll my `tableView` to recreate cell and than it is working again.

Reloading data doesn't help:

I was trying to define those values on:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

on my `viewController`, where I'm putting all data to this cell. But from there, my settings for scroll view are not working at all. I have no idea what to do with that thing. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is because **layoutSubviews** method in your code only invokes after initialization. But you need to execute the code inside this method even after coming back. For this you have to call **setNeedsLayout**

```
[self setNeedsLayout ];
```

Comment: Where should I add it? When I add it to Layoutsubviews cells are not working at all (blank tableview)

Comment: I've tried to add it at the end of cellForRowAtIndexPath: right before returning cell like that:

   [cellTab setNeedsLayout];

No result

Comment: I've checked that LayoutSubviews is called every time I'm going back to view Controller buy with no effect. So I've tried to find the problem. I thought that maybe the problem is with constraints, and I've tried to add them in the same method programically but than I've got info about trying to add multiple time the same constraints. I've also tried add [self.view setNeedDisplay]; to whole ViewController, it is also not taking any results. When I go back to view controller scroll doesn't work. I have to scroll table up and down, cell is recreating properly and scroll is working again.